# Creating a log of changes made via GridView?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, gridview, logging

I have a table (applicants) and using a GridView various individuals will be making changes to the values in this GridView. I've created another table (history) which I would like to use to log these changes. Right now I have this to capture the changes:

```
    Private Sub grdBusinessServices_RowUpdating(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles grdBusinessServices.RowUpdating
    Dim dbContext As pbu_checklistEntities = New pbu_checklistEntities
    Using dbContext
        Dim HistoryRecord As New History
    End Using
End Sub
```

I'm not sure how to capture the information that is changing though? In pseudo-code I want to do something like:

```
HistoryRecord.ChangedValues = grdBusinessServices.ChangedValues
```

Comment: You could use SQL to take the old value and add it to the History as a record .. will that work for you ?

Comment: Hmmm...I'd be interested to see how you would do that, though I'd prefer to avoid using straight SQL, since I'm doing everything else through LINQ.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not good with VB.NET nor LINQ .. but I can assure you it's a very simple INSERT command .. if you're good with LINQ you'll just retrieve the values in an object of type (Applicant) or local variables, of the data you want to log and when an update occurs check to see if the values are the same then do nothing, if there are new values entered then send the values you just stored in your object or local variables to the LINQ/ADO.NET method that will INSERT this record in the history table. I'll try to do a little search and i'll keep you informed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code to retrieve a value where "App_Name" is the column name you want to retrieve.

```
Dim a as string
a = GridView1.DataKeys(GridView1.SelectedIndex).Values("App_Name").ToString()
```

Now simply, after retrieving all the data place them in an object or you could use one in the first place -instead of using variables- and add it to your database with LINQ.

..I'm really not good with LINQ but I think this is a very simple and clear [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386941.aspx#Y565) I hope it helps